# Buscar folhas em uma bst e armazenar em um vetor em python

Tags: python, árvore-binária

Estou tentando criar uma função chamada folhas para localizar as folhas de uma arvore de busca binária e armazenar o valor contido nessas folhas em um vetor. Meu código fica retornando None, não entendo o porquê. Alguma idéia?

```
def folhas(self, lst):

    list = []

    if (self.dado == None):
        return 0;
    else:
        if (self.dado != None):
            if self.esquerda == None and self.direita == None:
                list.append(self.dado)
                print(list)
```

Comment: Sua função faz o `print` da lista que conterá um valor de folha. Ele não retorna nada, de fato; e no Python, quando uma função não executa um `return` explícito é retornado o valor `None`.

Comment: Sua função também está um pouco estranha, pois recebe como parâmetro um valor `lst` que não é usado, mas usa valores de `self.dado`, `self.esquerda` e `self.direita` que não existem no seu código, sendo impossível decifrar o que fez de fato.

Comment: **Geralmente** a busca por folhas em uma árvore é uma tarefa recursiva, então seria interessante pesquisar sobre o assunto.